# Storing the latest tweets by Joining 2 tables into C using hive

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive

I had 3 tables A,B the common things are tweeetId,account_id in the Both tables I want to join A and B for that I had witten a query

```
Select created_date, tweet_text, user_description
from A inner join
     B
     on A.tweetId = B.tweetId and A.account_id = B.accountid;
```

I want to take latest created_date after joining and B and then Compare that latest created date with C's most latest created date. so that the goal is to every time when query runs I need to insert data into C at the condition of Latest tweets existed in A and B has to dumped into C.

Comment: Do not clearly understand this "then Compare that latest created date with C's most latest created date". Do you need to not just insert latest into C but merge with already existing data?

Answer (score 0):

For getting latest tweets by date use row_number() function.
Like this:

```
insert overwrite C  --or insert into
select * from 
(
    select created_date, tweet_text, user_description
           row_number() over(partition by weetId, account_id order by created_date desc) as rn,
           tweetId, account_id --PK 
    from A inner join
         B
         on A.tweetId = B.tweetId and A.account_id = B.accountid
)s
where s.rn=1; --take the latest
```